# Enable Dell PowerEdge 830 withoud CD Rom drive to boot unattended

Tags: boot, dell-poweredge, bios, unattended

I removed the cd rom drive from a Dell PowerEdge 830

Now it does not start unattended anymore.

It boots normal, then halts at a line that says "strike F1 to continue, F2 to run setup". F1 would work here but that`s not what I want.

I searched the BIOS but there was no obvious solution.

What to do to make it startup unattended again without inserting a cd rom drive or pressing F1?

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! Looking above the line that says "strike F1 to continue, F2 to run setup," you almost certainly would have seen a specific error message pertaining to a missing IDE device. We were able to help you based on incomplete information only because you were describing a very common issue. If you come back with additional questions in the future, we would encourage you to provide as much relevant information as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to flag the IDE port that it doesn't have a device no more. It probably identifies it as an error, hence the attention mode.

Comment: I disabled the IDE port and the error went away. Thank you!